# in rails erb file i want to display an output as a decimal only at one place where actually it is showing as a float value

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

```
<div class='summary' align="justify" style='vertical-align: top;'>
  <div>
    {{:stats.tot_fte}} Employees Assigned 
    &emsp; {{:stats.tot_fte_effort}} Total Effort
  </div>
  <div>
    {{:stats.tot_users}} Users Assigned 
    &emsp;&emsp;&emsp; {{:stats.tot_user_effort}} Total Effort
  </div> 
</div>
```

this is the code which i wrote to display total effort as output where i calculate total effort at some other place,where it should always be float value as i use it for other calculations.But while displaying this here i want it to be a decimal value with two numbers after the decimal.please help me in completing this as i am a beginner.
The output is as follows,

> 340 Employees Assigned   340.89666666666665 Total Effort
>
> 453 Users Assigned     452.6066666666666 Total Effort

i want the total effort display as a decimal value only here.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Rails, it comes with a numbers helper in ActionView. You can use [`number_with_precision(number, options = {})`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_with_precision).

For example:

```
number_with_precision 123.456, precision: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Old School:

```
sprintf('%.2f', number)
```

Other:

```
(340.89666666666665).round(2)
```

Example:

```
{{:stats.tot_user_effort.round(2)}} Total Effort
{{sprintf('%.2f', :stats.tot_user_effort)}} Total Effort
```